# ImapLibrary - Robotframework: keyword "Wait For Email" when no mails in mailbox

Tags: robotframework, imaplib

My script is to open mailbox and delete all the emails.

```
Open Mailbox    host=outlook.office365.com  user=username   password=pass
${count}=   Wait For Email      
Delete All Emails           
Close Mailbox
```

If count returns value, the script works. But if no email in the mailbox, the keyword "Wait For Email" returns error: "*No email received within 60s*". Test case fails.

Can you help me ignore the failed error when no email in the mailbox? Tks a lot.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `wait for email` if you don't actually want to wait for email to arrive.

Comment: But if I don't use "wait for mail", the test case is always passed although no mails are deleted. I think may be the script runs so fast that it can't handle deleting all mails.

Comment: The `run keyword and ignore error  wait for email  timeout=1  poll_frequency=1` could be used to handle case when the mailbox is empty. And nevertheless, an exception was thrown inside the deletion will be successful.